# How do I merge multiple compose objects to a JSON array?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How do I create a JSON collection based on the Compose actions of the for each mentioned below? If I add a comma after the "}" it will be one too many at the end. Secondly, I somehow need to wrap it in a collection [ ]

I have a Foreach which has a Compose (iteration 1):

```json
{
    "Name": "A"
    "Value": "1"
}
```

Second Compose contains another object (iteration 2)

```json
{
    "Name": "B"
    "Value": "2"
}
```

However, I now do want to merge these composes to:

```json
"CollectionName": [{
        "Name": "A"
        "Value": "1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "B"
        "Value": "2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "C"
        "Value": "3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union)

```
union('<collection1>', '<collection2>', ...)
union([<collection1>], [<collection2>], ...)
```

You can refer to [Combine two JSON Arrays to one](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Combine-two-JSON-Arrays-to-one/m-p/759023#M242044) and [How can I merge the outputs from a For_Each loop in an Azure Logic App to a single flat array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763393/15969115)